# Declaration file missing when running ng test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, declaration-files

I recently started working on an existing Angular project The unit tests have been broken for quite some time. Unfortunatey, I haven't been able to get them running due to reference errors to an object that is defined in a declaration file. This declaration file is located in the root of the project. At runtime, the actual library is loaded from our development servers and everything works ok.

When running `ng test` however, Jasmine is complaining about references not being found:

```
    ReferenceError: SomeObject is not defined
        at <Jasmine>
        at MyService.getDetails (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/MyService.service.ts:196:33)
```

This is the tsconfig for the running app, which is running fine:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "someobject.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The test configuration is similar, but gives the above error:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "someobject.d.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The someobject.d.ts file is located in the root of the project, at the same level as polyfills.ts and main.ts.

This is only the second Angular app I have worked on, so I'm not that experienced in this area. It is also the first time that I have encountered a TypeScript declaration file. Most resources I found online are about dealing with declaration files distributed through npm for libraries like lodash. I found little to none information to work with declaration files in the project like this.

I'm looking for some pointers in the right direction to go from here.

Obviously, I edited class and filenames as I'm not at liberty to share source code verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things, I settled by adding the actual library and include it only for testing in angular.json:

```
"test": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
    "options": {
        ...
        "scripts": [
            "someobject.js"
        ],
        ....
    }
}
```

This way, the script is available when testing, but not included in production where it is provided by an external service.